# Cannot add programs installed via snap to Plank dock menu

Tags: plank

I just got elementary OS 6 yesterday and wanted to install Mailspring and Atom. I did so via snap.

In the applications menu both do not show and I have to open them via `snap run program_name`. When they are open, the icons show in the dock on the bottom but I have no option of keeping them in there. Also, the icons of these programs look kind of blurry.

With Firefox that I got via apt-get the issue does not occur.

Can anyone help? I would like to have them in there as it is more convenient and both are programs that I use regularly.

Thanks in advance!

Antonella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the AppCenter there is an application called AppEditor, with it you can create and modify shortcuts in the application menu, there is also another called alacarte that also allows you to do the same.

To install alacarte you can do it with the terminal using this command:

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

If this solves your question don't forget to mark as solved

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help Javier!